# Multiple Data Loaders on one machine

Tags: data-loader, dataloader-batch

Can I have multiple data loader instances running on the same machine ?

Scenario : I have data loader configured for production, now I want to configure another data loader for sandbox. Is that possible to use 2 data loaders form same machine 
Any suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: Why do you need two instances of the data loader? You can always use the same instance to connect to production/sandbox.

Comment: do you mean you want to use 2 data loader in parallel?

Comment: I'm Using Data Loader CLI on windows remote server desktop to schedule a daily import job that extracts data from Azure and updates into the salesforce custom object (production).Now the requirement is to configure another dataloader CLI and establish connection with sandbox. Can we have two data loaders running on same machine ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to configure multiple data loader.You can change Salesforce Login URL

For PROD use https://login.salesforce.com
For Sandbox use https://test.salesforce.com

[image]

Comment: I'm Using Data Loader CLI on windows remote server desktop to schedule a daily import job that extracts data from Azure and updates into the salesforce custom object (production).Now the requirement is to configure another dataloader CLI and establish connection with sandbox. Can we have two data loaders running on same machine ?